# Shield only combat

Tags: internal-consistency, warfare, combat, armors

Asking this for a more realistic view for ''rising of the shield hero' and possible uses in future writings. 
A shield is not a weapon, it is basically armor, that's why heavy armored knights rarely used shield and that's why hoplites didn't wear armor on their torso and upper legs, because the shield was just enough to cover almost the entire body.

When compared to body armor shields have advantages and also disadvantages, they are usually too heavy to be held on one arm by the average unfit person and soldiers were trained for tactics on how to kill and how to stay alive, not for strength but this had the advantages of lower cost when compared to armor and the ability to be moved around.

But so far I can't find a possible, hypothetical real life situation where wielding nothing but a shield as weapon is a good strategy.

Comment: At the risk of sounding glib given the millennia of human warfare it seems if the shield was an effective weapon then there would be plenty of historical evidence of them being used that way.  But that's not to say you could not contrive a way it might be done that would be entertaining.

Comment: Let's mention [Jon Snow vs Ramsay Bolton](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XTi-Y9KNNqk) showdown in season 6 of Game of Thrones.

Comment: Also see: [Shield Knight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shield_Knight) from the popular game Shovel Knight, or google "greatshield build dark souls" and see how they tackle the problem.

In both games, they're best coupled with another person who can attack from behind the person who is a dedicated guard.

Comment: A shield is only "basically armor" in Hollywood.  In actual combat, it was just as much a weapon as whatever you were holding in your other hand.

Comment: Captain America from Marvel Comics and Goofy from the Kingdom Hearts games are examples from fiction of only-shield-toting combatants. Goofy in particular uses a shield because he dislikes fighting, and while he does use it for melee combat, a lot of his abilities in the game are more based on supporting and defending his allies.

Comment: At the end of the day, the problem is that a shield makes a pretty crappy weapon. It doesn't give you extra reach OR extra mechanical advantage, so someone with an actual weapon will just beat on you until they get a shot past your shield and put you down. You can't win fights that way.

Answer (score 39):

Contrary to a lot of people's belief, shields were used as both an offensive and defensive weapon.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[Shield attack video](https://youtu.be/dkhpqAGdZPc?t=340)

However your problem is reach and penetration. You can bash an unarmored opponent with a shield fairly effectively or just barge into them with it. However a sword or mace will have more reach and penetrating power than your shield, and a spear or pole arm will be massively more.

There's a reason shield-only fighting was never really a thing. You want your weapon to have some combination of reach, speed, precision and penetrating power. Shields are not good at many of those things.

Comment: Shadiversity.... ^^

Comment: A hit from a Spartan shield would send you flying, crush bone, and pretty much kill you in a single blow.
It's a giant blunt object that is durable, and frequently has a small edge to focus the impact. So I agree completely, a shield is also a weapon, sometimes an extremely effective one.

Comment: Dude you wouldn't be able to reach someone to shield bash. Most cultures had spears, you'd be dead before even getting close enough to shield bash, a piece of wood could be used in battle, does that make it a good weapon? Shields are not nimble and you would be fighting someone that would have a shield + sword he would use it's shield to counter your's and than stab you.

Comment: @GaboSampaio A shield bash was a grappling move in many cases.  In others it was a deflection or disarmament.  Imagine trying to hold onto your spear when a warrior shoves his shield into your spear and pushes it out of your hand.

Comment: Sure but you are imaging we would be in shield range already.

Comment: Don't get me wrong i agree that shields are great weapons, I'm only stating a combination of different weapons is much more efficient.

Comment: @GaboSampaio It's a gamble on the spear user, thrust and risk hitting the shield, or wait for the shield barer to run you over with the shield.  A spear was a great weapon for getting over a shield, so it is an appropriate comparison.

Comment: They are really good otherwise we wouldn't have shield in most culture (i don't want to say all, but I'm pretty sure all civilizations had shields) We even use them until this day.

Comment: @GaboSampaio Your objections are covered explicitly in the last two paragraphs. I really have no idea why you're repeating their content in comments. But your objections do not change the historicity of offensive shield use. Even if it's less than ideal, combat is a messy business full of unexpected situations.

Comment: the association of Renaissance Martial Arts (ARMA) has a really good section on buckler combat that includes a picture using your [second shield to stab someone in the eye](http://www.thearma.org/essays/SandB/jw2-28.jpg)

Comment: you forgot dueling shields which often were used by themselves, lots of weapons are niche weapons that did not stop people from using them.

Answer (score 17):

While this might sound offensive (believe me, it's not), try watching the Marvel movies that feature Captain America:

- Captain America: The First Avenger
- The Avengers
- Captain America: The Winter Soldier
- The Avengers: Age of Ultron
- Captain America: Civil War
- The Avengers: Infinity War

I love watching his action scenes. They're actually quite creative as to what one can do with a shield. Of course we're both talking about an indestructible shield and basically a super human - but this is fiction. Why not, right?

Here's a [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=QP8l6J_H38g) to a 12 minute video that shows him in action.

Comment: This answer may be improved by adding links to videos of some of the fight scenes. What you're referencing is helpful, but "try watching 12 hours of movies" isn't quite so helpful.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Sorry about that. I don't have the time to look for that now 'cause I'm at work. But I'll edit this to make it even better. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: His shield is also somehow a combination of a Frisbee and a boomerang.  Very unrealistic :)

Comment: As long as we're on the topic of movie fiction, have a look at some of the "frisbee battles" from the (original) Tron movie ([represantative clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oVRo7g-epBM)).

Comment: Tron is truly awesome - and a great reference to have here. You also reminded me of the clash between Achiles and Hector in Troy. Achiles uses the shield in a very amazing way in that fight [clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ygRholyh5g)

Comment: The actual technique involved throwing a [buckler and dagger](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ms.Thott.290.2%C2%BA_077r.jpg) and was used enough to at least be included in manuscripts

Answer (score 13):

I've seen others comment on how the shield was used as an effective secondary weapon (and it was and would still be). However, since the question is "how can shield only combat be a good idea?" - I will add some real-life historical examples of how people tried (and in one case kinda succeeded) in using the "shield" as both weapon and defense:

#### Lantern Shields

These we know were real and [actually used in at least one duel/street fight](http://www.thearma.org/essays/digby.html#.XDbBYFxKir4) using the standard sword & buckler style. The fighter in the linked articles describes the shield & their usage:

> *[Shields] whose light was cast only forwards by their being made with an iron plate on that side towards the holders, so that their bodies remained in darkness, had not only the advantage of seeing him when he could not see them, but also dazzled and offended his eyes with the many near lights, which made him mistake those objects that dimly he discerned.*

However, there are some weird combinations of these that not only had a place for a lantern but were covered in blades:

[image: sword, gauntlet, lantern, and shield]

<sup>The above is a real piece from the 16th century, currently at the Kunsthistorisches Museum, Vienna</sup>

#### Sword Shields

Yeah, why use a sword and shield when you can have both in one convenient package:

[image: target with extendable sword]
<sup>yes the blade is extendable. yes, this means that the weapon in assasin's creed actually has some basis in reality</sup>

#### Gun Shield

Okay, there was a point in history where it seemed like they were trying to put a gun in everything. The odd part is though this one "failed" as a hand-held weapon, sources vary but most describe it as too hard/cumbersome to hold & aim by hand. It did have success when [mounted as anti-personnel weapons on ships](http://www.vam.ac.uk/content/journals/conservation-journal/issue-39/a-gun-shield-from-the-armoury-of-henry-viii-decorative-oddity-or-important-discovery/) and was a precursor to some modern riot shields and our modern [mounted gun shields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gun_shield):

[image: gun shield]

<sup>Italy, circa 1540 - Higgins Armory Museum</sup>

To add to the idea of gun shields, though modern versions are more a shield with a gun mounted behind it. At least one science fiction show, about a mad man in a blue box, has thought of how it could be adapted in the future to actually be more like its 15-16th century ancestor:

[image: Dr.Who Gun Shield]

#### It's all about the combinations

This is certainly stretching the idea of "shield only combat" but all of these are first and foremost **shields**. So if we allow an extending of the idea of shield only combat to include combination weapons (and use a little hand-waving to bypass the flaws) - its certainly possible.

Comment: @dhinson919 if anyone was going to figure out a way to make a shield a weapon - it would have to be that Doctor :)

Comment: It's worth noting that extendable blades are substantially weaker in construction than weapons built with a full tang, etc.

Comment: @Jason_c_o very true (there were similar issues with the blades on the lantern shields & both are very awkward to use). Hence, the "*hand-waving to bypass the flaws*" statement at end.

Answer (score 13):

Additionally to Tim B.'s very good answer about 'usual' and JGreenwell's covering of 'not-so-usual' shields there is a third category: [duel shields!](https://youtu.be/z9VG4ClQcJk?t=107).

[image]

They were made for and used as weapons in duels and a [form of martial arts](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/9c/86/15/9c86158e9f2a9420c3da7d01d8f599b6.jpg) was formed around their usage.

On the other hand there was also a wide variety of weapons (mostly daggers) for the explicit purpose of [parrying attacks](https://www.gladiatores.de/bilder/Heussler.jpg).

In other words: What is a "shield" and what is a "weapon" strongly depends on the context.

I think it certainly is possible to design combat around shields. But keep in mind that the "weapon + shield" combat or the "weapon + defensive weapon" or even a "one weapons suits it all" approach is the result of centuries of developement. Many lost their lives trying something new...

**Thanks to JGreenwell!** for posting this link: [dueling shield manual](https://www.freelanceacademypress.com/duelingshield.aspx)

It gives a great insight in how dueling shields were used.

Comment: gah! I was looking for those as part of my answer but just couldn't find them (duel shields kept giving me bucklers) - props for that but I did, finally, find a translated copy of one of [the manuscripts which started this strange tourney art](https://www.freelanceacademypress.com/duelingshield.aspx) <- if your interested or want to add it to post

Comment: @JGreenwell : Thank you very much! My search for "duel shields" yielded only the pictures and videos I posted above but not the manual I was looking for. You found exactly what I had searched for. I added it to my answer, thanks for posting it!

Answer (score 11):

## Less-lethal combat

A shield isn't just armour. The shield boss is a big lump of metal that can be used for bludgeoning. It's also for shoving while in a shield wall.

Your primary use would be riot and general crowd control, rather than combat. Situations where you don't actually want a bloodbath.

Comment: He asked for a realistic view.  Is there historical evidence that shields have been used in combat for bludgeoning?

Comment: @dhinson919, it's a standard use of a buckler

Comment: Bucklers are for "shield only" combat?

Comment: @dhinson919, a buckler is a small shield. I'm not sure what you're getting at here.

Comment: Per the OP's question are you suggesting that going into combat wielding nothing but a buckler is a good strategy?  If so I'm suggesting that historical evidence be provided to support that.  Otherwise it doesn't address the question or provide the realistic view asked for.

Comment: I think you're adding in more qualifications than necessary here. The answer is clear enough about what a Shield only Combat style would be used for. Other answers already point out the Shield + Bash, Attack, Slam as being used. If you're suggesting this answer should provide an effective shield fighting style (on par with weapon + shield or weapon fighting style) simply put that won't happen as there's no historical context for that (other answers show this). However, Shield Walls have been and are still used in the applications provided. And believe me, there's plenty of shield bashes there.

Comment: TBH, a shield bash with a buckler is closer to hitting someone with a gauntlet. Those things can get pretty small. Clearly not a first choice for life-or-death combat, but much better than bare-knuckles.

Comment: @dhinson919 "A buckler is a single-handed weapon and can be used in both [defense and attack](http://www.toxophilus.org/articles/anglais/sword_and_buckler_en.html)"

Comment: When it comes down to it anything can be used for defense and attack.  That was not the OP's question.  Reposting:"But so far I can't find a possible, hypothetical real life situation where wielding nothing but a shield as weapon is a good strategy."  Why don't you guys help this person out and provide a reason why wielding nothing but a buckler is a *good strategy*.

Comment: @dhinson919, OP didn't ask for a reason, OP asked for a situation, which I have given. I've only written two lines, do us all a favour and read both of them.

Answer (score 10):

Unlike in Holywood movies, melee weapons break when they get banged against other weapons and shields. Fight a long enough battle and you will be left without a weapon, not due to choice but because that's the reality of combat.

Until you can get a weapon from someone else who's out of combat, you will probably have only a shield. If you happen to face an enemy in such a situation, you have no other option but to use the shield.

Here is an example of how to use a shield as a weapon, taken from a famous TV show (warning graphic violence):

> [image: Tyrion is my second favorite character, right after Arya]

Comment: makes sense enough.

Answer (score 4):

You mean like dual-wielding shield? Or One Shield only?

Long Story short: Not realy.

There is no place in history evidencing dual wielding shield or shield only warfare. Someone with a sword (wich wasn't as used as one might think) spears were the most efficient and used weapon, cheaper, VERY effective, you would kill someone with a shield before the shield wilder could even reach you, yeah he may be able to defend against your spear, but for how long? Most people would have a buckler instead of a big shield, than buckler and sword, would be good for moving around on a daily bases.

Of course people would use shields for battles but that'd have their main weapon a side arm, very important people would have a shield bearer, POSSIBLY those shield bearers would use only shields for battles. But a sword and shield would be way more effective, a chair and a shield would be effective, a stone would be used in battle.

There is a reason we have swords, shields, spears in most cultures.

Comment: Spears did not guarantee you could kill someone with a shield, getting around a shield is hard with a spear at distance, and a shield wielder does not stay far away they close the distance, the spear wielder really only gets one shot. Which as why shield and spear together were used as often as sword and shield.

Comment: Try lifting a chair in one arm and swinging it as a weapon, especially while wielding a heavy shield.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any historical combat scenarios, but this is Worldbuilding, so:

Shield-only combat facilitates nonlethal combat, which could be used for ceremonious combat, such as challenges for leadership, et cetera. I imagine also it could be similar to types of wrestling, where the shields are used to knock opponents off their feet. It could be useful, as others have mentioned, when there is no other option in real combat. And using only a shield does allow one to carry a second shield for extra defense. Or both hands to increase movement potential.

Possibly, the wielder believes lethal force is immoral and as such only uses the weapon of defense. Also possible would be that the shield needs two hands to operate.

Comment: A ceremonial combat between two people competing for a prestigious title, lets say like a paladins shield bearer, a kings "high defender" or some other ceremonial defensive title. They are to utilize the tool of their desired position.

Comment: `Shield-only combat allows nonlethal combat` I disagree - pretty much anything used as a weapon can kill. If you instead mean that using a shield makes non-lethal combat possible, then consider that people fight with real swords to this day without dying. It's called fencing. So any weapon can also be used non-lethally (or rather *less*-lethaly).

Comment: Not to forget that some shields were explicitely made to kill (cf. the video linked in my answer and here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z9VG4ClQcJk&feature=youtu.be&t=107 ). Whether or not combat ends lethally almost entirely depends on the combattants (accidents can also happen).

Comment: Fine, @vlaz, but it sure is harder to accidentally kill someone with a shield than with other weapons. It seems rather intuitive to me that it would be better to use sheilds for non-lethal combat than swords.

Comment: @user45266 or box. Or wrestle. Or sumo. Or fence. Or play laser tag. We have lots of alternatives to using shields IRL. The fact that we are *not* using shields in formal nonlethal fights goes to show that it's not a preferred implement of choice. Your words make it seem like shields are either the only way to do that or that shields can never kill. Both of these are wrong as we can observe in the real world where we have shields. And this is what I disagreed with.

Comment: @vlaz If you wish, you may argue that shields are simply not the best choice for nonlethal combat, but seeing as OP's question revolves around using the shield, I beieve non-lethal combat still functions with shields, and therefore is a possible use. Also, I think the fact that we aren't using shields in formal nonlethal fights has a lot more to do with other reasons, like the scarcity and datedness of shields, and their portrayal in pop culture, to name a few.

Comment: But shields weren't scarce or dated in all the centuries before. Pop culture was also probably not that relevant to their image in the medieval and earlier times. And once again I have to explain that I disagree with your wording that suggests that either shields are *totally* non-lethal or that *only* shields allow for non-lethal format combat.

Comment: @vlaz I changed the word "allows". If you still object, then you and I will have to agree to disagree.

Answer (score 1):

It appears from your question, you are focusing on only single combat even if those singles are in a group.  Carrying only a shield or only a weapon was a strong tactic of groups, but in single combat, one usually held one of each for good reason.

While it is possible and is historically proven by several answers here, it is ill advised.  If you lose your shield due to damage or disarming, you've lost both your offense and defense.

Back in the day, there wasn't a Stack Exchange so folks had to try to build the one-offs in the hope of gaining an advantage or at least providing a distraction with the novelty.

Answer (score 0):

Shield only, *single* combat? No, that's like playing a life-gaining deck in MTG: there's no way for you to win except by concession of your opponent; lame.

As part of a **phalanx** it makes perfect sense. First rank shields, second rank swords, third rank spears.

Spears poke anyone too close. Get closer and the shields part so the swords can cut you down. Re-close shield wall. All advance one step. Repeat.

To see this in action go watch the first battle (~45min) in the movie *300*. Those shields are too small; imagine them full body size and you probably would need to use both hands. You'd likely have at least a dagger, but your *only* job is to literally hold the line. If you go down, so do the two others behind you.

Comment: Actually I won quite a few times in magic the gathering with life gaining decks when I used to play it.

Comment: @Hedwiros - Because they ran out of cards, or you cast a 20p fireball?

Comment: *"there's no way for you to win except by concession of your opponent"* unless you try smashing them in the face or throat with a solid & heavy block of metal or wood until they fall unconscious or die.  Or, you know, just punch them with your other hand while they're off-balance.

Answer (score 0):

Using a shield VS a two handed weapon is a trade off between better reach and offence, and more balanced offence/defence.

Your shield-hero could be someone who cares mainly about defence. Huge, pavise-like shields that an ally could hide behind too might develop in an open world that favours ranged encounters, where you can probably see the enemy long before getting the chance to get in mêlée range; in which case missile protection is your biggest concern.

Their offensive capability, then, would rely on moving in a testudo-like formation to advance under fire. If/when they get close, these are going to be your biggest strongest troops so would likely be able to push back enemy lines, or force a breach.

Either way you'd require a counterpart troop, either a shooter or long-pointy-stick-stabber. While your shield-warriors are great at protection, they would lack the actual damage output capability to be effective alone.

*Brave are those who charge to the fore with their fortress shields, claiming ground in enemy range.*

*Strong are those who push back the tide of flesh.*

*Revered are those who make the ultimate sacrifice, holding until death so that many can flee*

Answer (score 0):

Let me offer a more informative take on this by first delving into the details on 'The Four Cardinal Heroes' - Sword, Spear, Bow and the titular Shield.
The conditional restrictions being:

- Hero of [cardinal weapon] cannot use, equip or 'copy' a weapon TYPE other than what he has been summoned with;
- they more or less share the same skill trees, unlocks, forms, abilities, and 'Series' e.g. Mush(room) Series, Filolial (think chocobo) Series, and a plot-pivotal one, the Curse series (based on the Seven Deadly Sins) - a series that is much more powerful (and in the case of Naofumi, the Shield Hero, allows for damage-dealing and boss-killer tier 'thematic' attacks, but when used incurs very heavy penalties e.g. status debuff curses, long-term physical damage to the user,etc.)
- Upgrading and mastering unlocked versions/variants of [weapon] unlocks skills relevant to the variant being unlocked, and said abilities and skills can be used regardless of what [weapon] variant is currently equipped/active; in addition, the status buffs from unlocking and mastery all stack;
- the four Cardinal Heroes can work together to fight the Waves of Catastrophe (the reason they were summoned from their respective worlds); however, they cannot form a party with any two or all of them present in it for the purpose of leveling or similar activities, and thus must form their own parties each to do so. In addition, all four Heroes must be present whenever a Wave hits; otherwise the difficulty of said Wave increases drastically - or at least this was the reason given.

That being said, The Shield will obviously have the hardest circumstances, plot detraction aside, as they have little to no offensive ability. Naofumi picked the obvious choice of recruiting a party (in his case, slaves with a slave crest of loyalty engraved on them) to do the attacking, while he played his strengths, which are:

- Tanking damage
- protecting party members from receiving damage as well as using support skills (Erst Shield, Shield Prison, etc.) to make defeating enemies easier or more manageable
- Making full use of the utilitarian abilities unlocked in his Shield e.g. Potion Enhance, Growth Boost/Correction (for party members, essentially a leveling +stats enhancement buff), Blending/Compounding (medicinal item creation among other things) to further the well-being of the entire party in all aspects, including finance-wise.
- Instead of treating the world he was in as if it were a game, he took things in a serious, realistic manner, and protected the world's people from the Waves, fulfilling the very purpose he was summoned for; the resulting positive feedback benefited him and his party as time went on. In hindsight, it was a role befitting his cardinal weapon, and perhaps why he was chosen to wield it.

With all the informative exposition aside, the realistic approach would be to do what Naofumi did, and rely on teammates to do the attacking and damage while the shield wielder performs defense, logistics and support roles. 
Wielding a shield alone as only one person is rather difficult and more or less will depend on whether it is capable of dealing damage; there are methods and ways to do so, but it will more or less be on the level of 'difficult' and 'barely passable' - unless one possessed a shield with magical prowess similar to the Cardinal Shield, with all its potential for support skills and utilities - and even then, one would still need others to perform the offense roles.

Comment: Whilst fascinating and informative regarding your chosen topic, I believe that there is a misunderstanding here. The [tag:reality-check] tag has been used to require answers that relate to real-world uses of shields. You seem to be answering under the misapprehension that the question refers to the rules of [tag:magic] in the novel, it does not. Regardless, welcome to the forum and read-up in the [help] about how we work, it can take time to get used to the culture here. ([From review.](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/62832))